# modprobe: FATAL: Module not found

Tags: boot, drivers, 18.04, kernel, modprobe

I'm struggling to permanently insmod custom PCIe device drivers

Module can be loaded manually with `insmod ~\work\project\build\xdma.ko`

But I didn't manage to add it permanently.

I copied `xdma.ko` module to

```
$ ls /lib/modules/5.4.0-67-generic/kernel/drivers/xdma/
xdma.ko
```

And added `xdma` line to

```
$ cat /etc/modules
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
xdma
```

But it's not loaded during the boot. When I'm trying to reach it through modport command it says

```
modprobe xdma
modprobe: FATAL: Module xdma not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-67-generic
```

OS Details

```
$ hostnamectl
   ....
perating System: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-67-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

What else can I check to find the reason?

Comment: Other than possibly having it in the incorrect directory, you may have to `sudo update-initramfs -u` to update the ramdisk. Then reboot.